# Meaning of <T, U extends T> in java function declaration

Tags: java, generics, methods

I am seeing this:

```
public static <T,U extends T> AutoBean<T> getAutoBean(U delegate)
```

I know the input class is of U type and AutoBean class is of T type and U extends T is the boundary. But what does `<T,` mean here?

Also, if I am going to write a function to accept the output of getAutoBean, how would you write the function declaration? (i.e. myFunction(getAutoBean(...)), what will the function declaration of myFunction() be?)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you deliberately grouping `<T` together?  The `<` symbol is just part of the <> brackets.

Comment: No, I am just asking about the T in front of U extends T in the <> brackets.

Comment: The declaration can probably be improved, something like `<U> AutoBean<? super U> getAutoBean(U delegate)`

Comment: That signature is equivalent to `public static <T> AutoBean<T> getAutoBean(T delegate)`. The `U` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just declares the types that your method deals with. That is to say, that it basically has to first declare the generic type names, and only then use them in the signature. `<T` doesn't mean anything by itself, but the letters within angular brackets mean "Here are the types I am going to use in the method".

As to "myFunction()" to work with the output of `getAutoBean(...)`:

`public static  <T> String myFunction(AutoBean<T> arg){ // If you return a generic type object, you will also have to declare it's type parameter in the first angular brackets and in angular brackets after it.
    // do work here
}`

Comment: Thank you! I thought public static String is enough to say the return type is String. I didn't know I need an extra <T> before String (as in my original question <T, >

Comment: if you're going to do that, then might as well declare it as `public static String myFunction(AutoBean<?> arg)`

Comment: @Ibolit Sorry, but do you know an explanation of "the types that your method deals with"? 'til now I've thought, any method deals with its arguments and knows their type from the type declaration in the brackets (like `method(String arg1)`).

Comment: @malte I am sorry, I will not be able to provide you with a 100% accurate answer, but in the example above the type isn't actually known, it is not AutoBean, but it is AutoBean parameterized by something else. We don't know yet by what, and T is not a type, it is a kin of a variable. If it were declared in the class declaration, we wouldn't need it in the method declaration before the return type. I am sure there are better explanations.

Answer (score 4):

`<T>` is the type of the AutoBean that will be returned by the method.
Also notice that input parameter type `<U>` has to extend type `<T>` for invoking the method.

Answer (score 4):

`<T,U extends T>` is declaring the type parameters for a static method.  This method has two type parameters, a type `T`, and a second type `U` that extends the first.

These can be different when you explicitly specify bindings for type parameters as in

```
AutoBean<Object> autoBean = Foo.<Object, String>getAutoBean("delegate");
```

assuming `getAutoBean` is a member of class `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

It means the type `U` must extend the type `T`. For example, these types could be used in place of `T` and `U`.

```
class TType { }
class UType extends TType { }
```

As for what `<T,` means, it's declaring the generic type to be used in the function. Here is example usage:

```
UType uType = new UType();
AutoBean<TType> autobean = getAutoBean(uType);
```

Answer (score 2):

As lbolit said,  declares what your method deals with, i.e. in this case a return type of T and a parameter of U which is a subclass of T.